# Application Request Routing server requirements

Tags: web-server, arr

I'm exploring the possibility of implementing ARR for a basic webfarm.  For the foreseeable future there will be at most 500-1000 users during peak usage.  The site is for OLTP -- no content streaming.  Can anyone provide some guidance as to what sort of system specs are required for that type of moderate load?  Or perhaps any benchmark results that you're aware of?

I've had trouble finding any data on CPU / memory usage for a dedicated ARR server.  Given limited resources,  I want to avoid spending on an unnecessarily powerful server so that I can sufficiently fund the web servers in the farm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen sizing recommendations from Microsoft for ARR.

That being said, if you're not using caching in the ARR layer then the specs are minimal. Without caching, the ARR service isn't doing much. A single low-end server will probably handle your user load. Make sure that whatever NIC is in the server is known to work well with Receive Side Scaling. Also, if I had a choice between two small servers running NLB and ARR vs. one larger server, I would go for the two smaller servers for redundancy.

If you are using caching, I would recommend a single processor with lots of core and lots of fast RAM. If you get multiple processors then you will have to deal with NUMA affinity, which I don't think ARR's cache mechanism understands.